# Can Sphinx Search RealTime (RT) Indexes have Multi-Value Fields?

Tags: sphinx

Is there a way to get the equivalent of an `rt_field_multi` (instead of an `rt_attr_multi`) in Sphinx Search?  I have a database that has multiple numeric codes that are associated with each record.  I'd like to be able to index those codes, but I can't figure out how to get an RT index to accept a multi-value indexed field.  Is this possible?  Is there a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that currently that is only supported in plain indexes, using [`sql_joined_field`](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-joined-field).

However, you can concatenate those codes, separated by spaces, and save them in a `rt_field`. They will be indexed as usual, and you will be able to search on them using `MATCH('"<code>"')` or even more specifically with `MATCH('@field_name "<code>"')`.

Comment: exactly. In effect a normal field is 'multi value' :) A field typically contains many words.

Comment: Glad it helped. If this answers your question, you should accept it to tell the other users that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already numeric codes, just use these in your `INSERT INTO rt_index (id, field_name) VALUES (456, (1,2,3))`.

Note that you have to use a different format than the SQL format for plain indexes, where you would have `INSERT INTO plain_index (id, field_name) VALUES (456, '1,2,3')`